# CORS Setting work in GET But not in case of POST in Slim 2

Tags: php, angular, slim

I am using Angular 5 as front and Slim 2 as back. Slim allows me to complete my GET requests but it doesn't allow me in POST requests.

I have added headers of CORS in my index.php file. But it doesn't work.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Please help if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: What, precisely, is the error message that you recieve?

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Answer (score 2):

You code will, when the index page is requested, grant permission for JS to read the response.

Your JS is, however, generating [a preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) (which will be OPTIONS rather than POST). It won't send the POST request until the server responds with permission.

Your server needs to respond to it with a `200 OK` response and appropriate `Access-Control-Allow` origin headers. However, your server is currently throwing a `500 Internal Server Error` instead.

You need to look at your server side code and fix that error so that it responds correctly to the OPTIONS request.

Comment: I have already written a code for **Access-Control-Allow origin** in my server. It allows GET requests.

Comment: @user2256601 — Yes, I acknowledged that on the first line of this answer. Please read the rest of the answer.